# Listing app's Android dependencies from within a Gradle task

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-library, gradle-plugin

I am building a Gradle plugin that checks the dependencies of an app for a particular version of my library, and downloads a configuration file specific to that version.

**Question**: How can a plugin get all/some dependencies' versions of the project into a string?

In a way, I want to have a task which consumes (and then parses) the screen output of the `androidDependencies` task.

*What have I tried*:

1. Read the project's dependencies as they are. Didn't work as I could only get the dependencies before they are resolved into actual versions (the '+' version, or some other resolve strategy the app might exhibit).
2. Reverse-engineered the `androidDependencies` task to see how I could do the same, and instead of `println`, append to a string. Too time-consuming, and didn't feel like the right approach anyway.
3. From within a task in my plugin, spawn a process that executes `./gradlew dependencies` and directs the output of that process into a string. This works but launching a new gradle daemon takes time, and the task finishes in about 5 seconds instead of what should be instantaneous.

Is there a better solution?